# Как получить доступ к элементам главного окна, созданного из .ui?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Есть файл main.ui В котором содержится окно с его элементами (созданного через PyQT Designer).
Как получить к ним доступ для установки кнопкам реакцию на события?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys



class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.show()
    def getbtn(self):
        return self.start


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()


app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Designer` (в `.ui` тоже можно увидеть в атрибуте `name`) у виджетов есть свойства `objectName`. Вот эти свойства и станут названием элемента в поле класса.

Например, у вас есть кнопка с `objectName` = `pushButton`, тогда к ней можно обратиться как:

```
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide)
        self.show()
...
```